# How to add accordian items in ngFor loop in Angular?

Tags: angular, accordion

I want dynamic accordion items in angular which I get from API response.
This is my accordion html:

```
                        <div id="accordion" class="custom-accordion">
                            <div class="card" *ngFor="let notification of Notification; let i=index;">
                                <div class="card-header" [attr.id]="'heading' + i">
                                    <h5 class="mb-0">
                                        <button class="btn btn-link " 
                                            data-toggle="collapse"
                                            [attr.data-target]="'#collapseItem' + i"
                                            aria-expanded="true"
                                            [attr.aria-controls]="'collapseItem' + i">
                                            Notification
                                            <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-up ">&nbsp;</i>
                                        </button>
                                    </h5>
                                </div>

                                <div [attr.id]="'collapseItem' + i" class="collapse show"
                                    [attr.aria-labelledby]="'heading' + i"
                                    data-parent="#accordion">
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        {{ notification.quote }}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Now, the problem is that every accordion have same id. If I open one accordion all the others accordion get open & same happens for close.
Please help..

Comment: whats the problem here?

Comment: `<div id="accordion" class="custom-accordion" *ngFor="let notification of Notification; let i=index;"> ...` have you tried this?

Comment: The problem is that every accordion have same id. If I open one accordion all the others accordion get open & same for close.

Answer (score 2):

Use different ids based on index for this to work.

```
<div id="accordion" class="custom-accordion">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let notification of Notification; let i=index;">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link " 
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    [data-target]="'#collapse'+i"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseOne">
                {{ notification.title }}
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-up ">&nbsp;</i>
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div [id]="'collapse'+i" class="collapse show"
            aria-labelledby="headingOne"
            data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ notification.body }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so I make it to the half way. See edited question at the top. But aria-expanded="true" make every accordion item opened up. Can anyone help me to set it false when one accordion item is open.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: it's ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0

Comment: Then shouldn't you be using 'accordion' components from ngx bootstrap instead of plain css accordion?

Comment: I mean something like this?
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/5.2.0/#/accordion#one-time

So you would not need to use aria and data attributes.
This would make things lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

add attr. for this to work
`

```
<div id="accordion" class="custom-accordion">
    <div class="card" *ngFor="let notification of Notification; let i=index;">
        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn btn-link " 
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    [attr.data-target]="'#collapse'+i"
                    aria-expanded="true"
                    aria-controls="collapseOne">
                {{ notification.title }}
                <i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-angle-up ">&nbsp;</i>
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div [attr.id]="'collapse'+i" class="collapse show"
            aria-labelledby="headingOne"
            data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                {{ notification.body }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`
```